# How to parse a CSV file as with commas or pipes and read into a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop through multiple CSV files in a folder and parse each file into a data frame then get the data type for each field.  Before I can even get to the loop, I'm trying to parse a single CSV file, and I'm encountering some issues.  This is what I'm working with now.

```
import pandas as pd
# CSV file
csv_file = 'C:\\path\\ARMINDEX.CSV'
# read cvs with pandas read_csv
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df.dtypes
```

Comment: You can make of strip to remove whitespace and replace pipe with commas.

Comment: You can use the approach in this other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949955/changing-pipe-separated-data-to-dataframe-in-python-pandas

Comment: @ ryguy72 See the answer below, i believe that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have pipe"|" delimited fields, which you can try like below with a regex separator `sep="|"`, However you can use altogether `skipinitialspace=True` to Skip spaces after delimiter.

```
import pandas as pd
# CSV file
csv_file = 'C:\\path\\ARMINDEX.CSV'
# read cvs with pandas read_csv
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep="|", skipinitialspace=True, header=None)
```

If you need to assign names to the delimited Feilds to get them a Name, you can try..

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep="|", skipinitialspace=True, index_col=False, newCols=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
```